# Access to table pivot in laravel

Tags: laravel, controller

I have the following model in Shopping. This is connected in many to many reglations with another Product table. I would like the pivot table data to be returned to me when I make an axios call to shopping. For example `Shopping :: all () -> load ('pivot_table`). How could I do it from the controller?

Answer (score 0):

In the shopping model add this function:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product');
}
```

In controller call this to get shopping data with products:

```
Shopping::with('products')->all();
```

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)